# How to set volatile array to zero using memset?

Tags: c++, arrays, volatile, memset

```
volatile uint8_t reset_mask[768] = {0}
```

Now I am setting the values of this array elements to 1 during one of internal operations.

In another functional call, I need to set all the elements of this array to 0. One way is by using for loop but I believe better way to assign all the elements of array is by using memset

```
memset(reset_mask, 0, sizeof(reset_mask));
```

but I am getting this error :-
"cast from type 'volatile uint8_t* {aka volatile unsigned char*}' to type 'void*' casts away qualifiers"

In case we cannot use memset here, is there a better way to set all elements of this volatile array in one go?

Comment: `std::fill(std::begin(reset_mask), std::end(reset_mask), 0);` works.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That should be an answer (since it is really the only correct answer).  In C, of course, he'd have to use his own loop.

Comment: What are you using the volatile array for?  You may have to disable some/all interrupts?

Comment: Is there any good reason why you are using volatile. Volatile should only ever be used for memory mapped FIFO registers where memset is totally inappropriate. Please do not use volatile in multithreading. Rather use appropriate locks.

Comment: Volatile is used because reset_mask is used by multiple PUs concurrently running the same code and modifying the value of array elements. In my situation, there is a condition placed where it checks while(reset_mask[pu]==0){..//It is not setting reset_mask inside this loop so if we don't use volatile, due to compiler optimization this may get optimized into while(true). Usage of Volatile keyword prevents such compiler optimization.......}

Comment: Use locks. Remember that read and writes may be reordered. Volatile just effect compilation and has no effect on CPU behaviour. If you want to guarantee read and write ordering across threads, your CPU will provide Data Memory Barriers. There will be incorporated into the appropriate locks, Volatile is not the way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612505/is-volatile-needed-in-this-multi-threaded-c-code/3612551#3612551

Comment: @doron - 'Please do not use volatile in multithreading' - indeed. I assumed 'reset_mask' was some kind of drivery, interruptery thing where 'volatile' was actually useful.

Answer (score 9):

You "can" use `memset` casting away volatileness with `const_cast`, but it will remove the volatile semantics. So unless that is okay for you, you're stuck with the loop version. Unless your implementation gives you a version of memset that takes volatile* and is documented to do your job. (I'd think unlikely outside embedded systems, would surprise me even there.)

Answer (score 6):

As Balog Pal said, casting away `volatile` to call `memset` breaks the `volatile` semantics. The whole `memset` may get optimized away, or undefined behaviour badness happens.

Either write your own loop to zero out the array, or use this `memset_volatile`:

```
void memset_volatile(volatile void *s, char c, size_t n)
{
    volatile char *p = s;
    while (n-- > 0) {
        *p++ = c;
    }
}
```

The real `memset` also returns `s` and `c` is an `int`, but this version is cleaner to me.

It is quite unclear if the compiler is allowed to optimize this function to write more than one byte at a time, so if the array is very large it could be a bit slow.

Edit: Since C11 there is [memset_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). It doesn't take a pointer to volatile for some reason, so you have to cast away the volatile. It is however guaranteed to actually overwrite the memory.

Comment: `memset_s` does not guaranteed to actually overwrite the memory. `memset_explicit` (C23) does.